# Nodejs child_process exec not running /bin/bash

Tags: node.js, bash

I am trying to run a bash instance from node js but nothing seems to happen when I run the following code:

```js
const { execSync } = require("child_process");
execSync("/bin/bash");
```

Then when I run `ps` to see if there is another bash process running there is no extra bash process running.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That just stops the bash prccess from exiting. I want it to actually run.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Is there anyway to achieve opening a prompt like if you were to run it right from the terminal in nodejs.

Comment: Executing `/bin/bash` programatically without additional parameters will result in bash process directly exiting. Try `/bin/bash -c 'sleep 30'` and you should be able to check for the `bash` process running using `ps`.